# CE mark on a PCB sold as a part of a kit or part of a project, necessary?

Tags: pcb, certification, ce

I've a prototype that I want to sell as a product. My prototype is made by an aluminium structure, a motor, a moving part (made by 3D printer) and an electronic circuit. 
The electronic circuit is made by an Arduino, a motor shield and a simple PCB on top of it (the green one in the image) [image]

The only parts that I've exclusively are the aluminium structure, 3D component and the PCB.

**Should I CE marks the PCB if**:

1. I sell the entire product as a kit?
2. I sell only the exclusive parts, making available instructions to mount them with other components (*not sold by me*)?

Comment: are you selling it in or importing it to the EU?

Comment: Sure, I'm selling from EU to EU. Sorry, I just assumed it.

Comment: Basically every product sold in the EU needs a CE mark. You can study more here https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/manufacturers_en

Comment: @TemeV In reality there're a lot of product that didn't need a CE mark on it, Arduino didn't have it for example and the shield I'm using also haven't it. That's why I'm asking here for help!

Comment: This is a legal question not an electronics question. CE marking are required for consumer electronics sold in the EU. Arduino own warranty states CE and FCC markings ( https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/warranty )

Comment: @JonRB - I once saw a plastic serving tray that had a CE mark!

Comment: @JonRB the only answered questions about CE marks are in this stack_exchange site, I'm sorry if this is not the right place to find an answer but I hoped someone can help me. Anyway, about CE on Arduino I said that it didn't have it (Arduino implemented it just recently).

Comment: Yup, there are products that don't have the mark on them, but it doesn't mean it is the correct way. To put it bluntly, if you don't know do you need the mark on your product, you probably aren't aware of the requirements EU has set for it. It means you probably should not sell them, before you figure those out.

Comment: Reading any kind of EU directives there's a paragraph for products that doesn't need to be marked. Just saying, in the EMC directive, components like transistors don't need to be marked.

Comment: Like @JonRB mentions the mark is intended for CONSUMER electronics and like Huisman below writes they are not needed for research gear.  Also the testing is internal as you assert that it complies, you only have to prove it if there is a query.  If you have a simple (switch, resistor and low voltage battery) LED torch you can safely use a CE mark with no testing.  If you make an oscillating high voltage apparatus you are advised to do it right and have the design tested.

Comment: Questions about CE marking are fine, as long as they are related to electronics. See this: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6878/can-i-ask-about-product-requirements-on-european-standards

Comment: You need to CE mark the finished product that is put on market. A PCB is rarely ever a finished product, so it doesn't make sense to CE mark it most of the time. Arduino is sold as a stand-alone product to random hobbyists who often don't have a clue what they are doing, so it most likely needs CE marking. It is marketed as a hobbyist kit so they can't get away by saying it is only for professionals and R&D use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I CE marks the PCB if:
>   1.I sell the entire product as a kit?
>   2.I sell only the exclusive parts, making available instructions to mount them with other components (not sold by me)?

**sell entire product**
If you want to sell the entire product, you should [satisfy all applicable directives](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/manufacturers_en), one of them being the EMC directive<sup>(1)</sup>.
If product A is EMC and product B is EMC, then their sum is **not by definition** also EMC. So, you need to prove the entire product satisfies the EMC directies, having to perform all EMC tests again...

**sell exclusive parts**
If you sell exclusive parts, you might avoid the EMC directive (not sure about the other directives) refering to Article 2, clause 2 (d)

> equipment the inherent nature of the physical characteristics of which is such that:
>   (i) it is incapable of generating or contributing to electromagnetic emissions which exceed a level allowing radio and telecommunication equipment and other equipment to operate as intended; and
>   (ii) it operates without unacceptable degradation in the presence of the electromagnetic disturbance normally consequent upon its intended use;

as the aluminium structure and the PCB will satisfy this exception (can't say it from the unknown 3D component)

or avoid the EMC directive by writing in the **intended use** of your product it is only for professionals to be used solely at research and development facilities for such purposes, and refer to Article 2, clause 2 (e)

> custom built evaluation kits destined for professionals to be used solely at research and development facilities for such purposes.

The text at the end of Article 2

> For the purposes of point (c) of the first subparagraph, kits of components to be assembled by radio amateurs and equipment made available on the market and modified by and for the use of radio amateurs are not regarded as equipment made available on the market.

applies to **radio amateurs** and cannot by definition be generalised to everyone.

<sup>(1)</sup> Another one is: Restriction of Hazardous Substances in Electrical and Electronic Equipment, and there are also General Product Safety, WEEE, etc)